# Sum integer list when next integer is the same value

Tags: python, sum, integer

So I need to have a code that checks one integer, and checks if the integer after it is the same value. If so, it will add the value to `x`.

```
input1 = [int(i) for i in str(1234441122)]
x= 0
```

So my code currently gives the result `[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1 ,2 ,2]`. I want it to give the result of `x = 0+4+4+1+2`.
I do not know any way to do that.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried to use print (1(input1)) to see if that would show the first integer, but that didn't work.

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the rest of the code you tried

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following will work. Zip together adjacent pairs and only take the first elements if they are the same as the second ones:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2]
>>> sum(x for x, y in zip(lst, lst[1:]) if x == y)
11
```

While this should be a little less [space-]efficent in theory (as the slice creates an extra list), it still has `O(N)` complexity in time and space and is well more readable than most solutions based on indexed access. A tricky way to avoid the slice while still being concise and avoiding any imports would be:

```
>>> sum((lst[i] == lst[i-1]) * lst[i] for i in range(1, len(lst)))  # Py2: xrange
11
```

This makes use of the fact that `lst[i]==lst[i-1]` will be cast to `0` or `1` appropriately.

Comment: A bit shorter: `sum((i and x == lst[i-1]) * x for i, x in enumerate(lst))`

Answer (score 4):

Another way using `itertools.groupby`

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1 ,2 ,2]
from itertools import groupby
sum(sum(g)-k for k,g in groupby(l))
#11
```

Comment: Or `sum(sum(g) - k for k, g in groupby(l))`.

Comment: I like this one, too :) very creative!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
s = str(1234441122)
new_data = [int(a) for i, a in enumerate(s) if i+1 < len(s) and a == s[i+1]]
print(new_data)
final_data = sum(new_data)
```

Output:

```
[4, 4, 1, 2]
11
```

Comment: instead of `i+1 < len(s)` you could simply slice the string. `input1 = sum([int(n) if n == str_repr[i+1] else 0 for i, n in enumerate(str_repr[:-1])])`

Answer (score 2):

You are simply iterating on string and converting character to integer. You need to iterate and compare to next character.

```
a = str(1234441122)
sum = 0
for i,j in enumerate(a[:-1]):
    if a[i] == a[i+1]:
        sum+=int(a[i])
print(sum)
```

Output

```
11
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for that list. You can remove the "non-repeated" digits from the *string* already:

```
>>> n = 1234441122
>>> import re
>>> sum(map(int, re.sub(r'(.)(?!\1)', '', str(n))))
11
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one too:

```
input1 = [int(i) for i in str(1234441122)]
x= 0
res = [input1[i] for i in range(len(input1)-1) if input1[i+1]==input1[i]]
print(res)
print(sum(res))
```

Output:

```
[4, 4, 1, 2]
11
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly more space efficient version of @schwobaseggl's answer.

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2]
>>> it = iter(lst)
>>> next(it) # throw away first value
>>> sum(x for x,y in zip(lst, it) if x == y)
11
```

Alernatively, using an `islice` from the `itertools` module is equivalent but looks a bit nicer.

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> sum(x for x,y in zip(lst, islice(lst, 1, None, 1)) if x == y)
11
```